# Two different sine waves produce same output?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, matlab-stem

I ran this code in matlab and expected different figures, but I got them identical (beside the title). I am pretty sure they should produce a different output but they aren't. What is happening here?

```
n = [0 : 63];

x1 = sin(2*pi*n/16);
figure(1);
stem(n, x1);
title('x_1(n) = sin(2*pi*n/16)')
ylabel('x_1(n)')
xlabel('n')

x2 = sin(2*pi*17*n/16);
figure(3);
stem(n, x2);
title('x_2(n) = sin(2*pi*17*n/16)')
ylabel('x_2(n)')
xlabel('n')
```

Comment: How are you determining if they are the same or not?

Comment: @Paul I compare the two figures.

Comment: I don't know matlab but is there any chance it's scaling the x axis so they look the same?

Comment: The second sine has `n` extra turns at sample `n` compared with the first. Complete turns amount to nothing

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, it depends purely on the n chosen. If it was continuous the results would be totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose `n` in such a unlucky manner, that by chance you sample only points where both waves are identical. Try `n = [0 :0.25: 63];`

Here are both plots with an increased sample rate. In red the identical points you sampled:

[image]
[image]

`ezplot` is a good choice to avoid such issue:

```
ezplot(@(n)(sin(2*pi*n/16)))
hold on
ezplot(@(n)sin(2*pi*17*n/16))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are working on discrete time signals. Thus, they are exactly identical for **discrete time**. Discrete time means time vector has `1` of time step (fs = 1). If you changed the time step, this means it wouldn' t be a discrete time signal anymore and period calculation would be performed by different way (I mean you wouldn't need a `k` value to make period discrete, see below for what `k` is) so they would look different signals because their periods would be different.

Yes the plots are identical. Because, they have the same period.

Lets calculate their periods:

**For First Signal**

```
x1 = sin(2*pi*n/16);
```

Period Equation:

```
2*pi/16 = 2*pi*k/(N1)
     N1 = 16*k   | k=1
     N1 = 16
```

Where `N1` is the period of first signal. `k` is due to guarantee make `N1` discrete means integer value. `k` is also an integer value (`k=1,2,3, ...`). You must chose `k` as min value of it making `N1` discrete. So here, fundamental `k` is chosen as `1`.

**For Second Signal**

```
x2 = sin(2*pi*n*17/16);
```

Period Equation:

```
2*pi*17/16 = 2*pi*k/(N2)
        N2 = 16/17*k   | k=17
        N2 = 16
```

where fundamental `k` is chosen as `17`. Because you are working on discrete time and there is no value like `16/17` in discrete time domain; period must be **integer** value.

Signals that have a same period with same phase, means they look like identical.

Comment: They are not the same! It depends on the n.

Comment: @Igor - They are exactly same for DISCRETE TIME, I mean for time step = 1 (fs = 1). If you changed the time step, this means it wouldn' t be a discrete time signal and they would look like different signals. I will improve my answer.